# angular cannot find module @angular-devkit\core\node_modules\rxjs\dist\cjs\index.js

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, angular-devkit

To run the program, we have a batch file called buildAndRun.bat that cleans Maven, then it installs Node and NPM in case they aren't already there. After this it runs `ng build --configuration production`. Every step works fine up until it actually tries to build the application.

It runs `ng build --configuration production`. but whenever it does, it throws an error that it cannot find the module:

`M:Application Production\frontend\node_modules\@angular-devkit\core\node_modules\rxjs\dist\cjs\index.js`

The issue is that within `rxjs`, there is no `dist` directory. So I'm not surprised at the error, I just don't know why it's not generating the `dist` directory.

Here's what I have installed:

```
Node                            18.16.1
npm                             9.7.2

@angular-devkit/architect       0.1601.4
@angular-devkit/build-angular   16.1.4
@angular-devkit/core            16.1.4
@angular-devkit/schematics      16.1.5
@angular/cli                    16.1.5
@angular/language-service       16.1.6
@schematics/angular             16.1.5
rxjs                            6.5.5
typescript                      4.9.5
zone.js                         0.13.1
```

I've tried deleting and reinstalling `@angular-devkit`, but it still won't generate the necessary files. I've also tried doing a fresh install of Node to see if that might have been the issue, but that also doesn't seem to work. It should just build the application, but as above, it just throws the `Cannot find module` error. The part I don't understand is that it was working fine a week ago, and I haven't made any changes to it since then.

**EDIT:**

Tried what @MatthieuRiegler said, but it just resulted in the following errors:

```
[INFO]     Error occurs in the template of component HeaderComponent.
[INFO]
[INFO]
[INFO] Error: src/app/header/header.component.html:24:79 - error NG8002: Can't bind to 'formGroup' since it isn't a known property of 'form'.
[INFO]
[INFO] 24     <form *ngIf="currentUserRole !== 'none'" class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0" [formGroup]="searchForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
[INFO]                                                                                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
[INFO]
[INFO]   src/app/header/header.component.ts:9:16
[INFO]     9   templateUrl: "./header.component.html",
[INFO]                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
[INFO]     Error occurs in the template of component HeaderComponent.
[INFO]
[INFO]
[INFO] Error: src/app/home.component.html:92:89 - error NG8002: Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'input'.
[INFO]
[INFO] 92                 <input type="date" id="start_date" class="date-input" name="start_date" [(ngModel)]="start_date">
[INFO]                                                                                            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
[INFO]
[INFO]   src/app/home.component.ts:11:16
[INFO]     11   templateUrl: './home.component.html',
[INFO]                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
[INFO]     Error occurs in the template of component HomeComponent.
[INFO]
[INFO]
[INFO] Error: src/app/home.component.html:96:85 - error NG8002: Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'input'.
[INFO]
[INFO] 96                 <input type="date" id="end_date" class="date-input" name="end_date" [(ngModel)]="end_date">
[INFO]                                                                                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
[INFO]
[INFO]   src/app/home.component.ts:11:16
[INFO]     11   templateUrl: './home.component.html',
[INFO]                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
[INFO]     Error occurs in the template of component HomeComponent.
[INFO]
[INFO]
[INFO] Error: src/app/home.component.html:103:58 - error NG8004: No pipe found with name 'date'.
[INFO]
[INFO] 103             <span class="current-date">{{ currentStart | date:'MM/dd/yyyy' }} - {{ currentEnd | date:'MM/dd/yyyy' }}</span>
[INFO]                                                              ~~~~
[INFO]
[INFO]   src/app/home.component.ts:11:16
[INFO]     11   templateUrl: './home.component.html',
[INFO]                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

**EDIT 2:**

Here's my package.json as requested by @Andrei

```
{
    "name": "angular-nodejs-example",
    "version": "0.0.0",
    "scripts": {
        "ng": "ng",
        "start": "ng serve",
        "build": "ng build",
        "test": "ng test",
        "lint": "ng lint",
        "e2e": "ng e2e"
    },
    "private": true,
    "dependencies": {
        "@angular/animations": "16.1.7",
        "@angular/common": "16.1.7",
        "@angular/compiler": "16.1.7",
        "@angular/core": "16.1.7",
        "@angular/forms": "16.1.7",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "16.1.7",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "16.1.7",
        "@angular/router": "16.1.7",
        "@canvasjs/angular-charts": "^1.0.3",
        "@canvasjs/charts": "^3.7.12",
        "@fullcalendar/angular": "^6.1.8",
        "@fullcalendar/core": "^6.1.8",
        "@fullcalendar/daygrid": "^6.1.8",
        "@fullcalendar/timegrid": "^6.1.8",
        "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^15.1.0",
        "@ngrx/effects": "^16.0.0",
        "@ngrx/entity": "^16.0.0",
        "@ngrx/router-store": "^16.0.0",
        "@ngrx/store": "^16.0.0",
        "@ngrx/store-devtools": "^16.0.0",
        "@popperjs/core": "^2.11.8",
        "angular-oauth2-oidc": "^15.0.1",
        "bootstrap": "4.1.1",
        "canvasjs": "^1.8.3",
        "ngrx": "0.0.1-security",
        "ngrx-store-freeze": "^0.2.4",
        "ngrx-store-localstorage": "^16.0.0",
        "rxjs": "~6.5.4",
        "tslib": "^2.0.0",
        "typescript": "^4.8.4",
        "zone.js": "~0.13.0"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "16.1.4",
        "@angular/cli": "16.1.5",
        "@angular/compiler-cli": "16.1.7",
        "@angular/language-service": "16.1.6",
        "@types/jasmine": "~3.5.0",
        "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
        "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
        "codelyzer": "^6.0.2",
        "jasmine-core": "3.8.0",
        "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
        "karma": "~6.4.2",
        "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
        "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
        "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
        "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
        "protractor": "~7.0.0",
        "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
        "tslint": "~6.1.0"
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like this kind of deps issues that can be solved by deleting the lock file and the `node_modules`.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your response @MatthieuRiegler ! That's what I saw a lot of other posts recommend, but in my case it didn't fix anything, it seems to break it more. I tried your solution for posterity's sake, but it didn't help. I don't understand why, because a week ago it was working fine, and I haven't touched anything in the program since that week. Nobody else has access to the application either, it's just me. Anyway, I edited the post with the results.

Comment: Your edit looks like one of your modules doesn't compile anymore.

Comment: are you using yarn/pnpm or just npm? could you also please provide your whole package.json? there could be some other things rather than dependencise

Comment: @Andrei I'm just using npm. I added the package.json like you requested.